# Store files dowloaded by daemon

Tags: linux, storage, daemon

I'm writing a daemon, which should upload images for given URLs, so the question is where to store this images. This daemon may run as a user that doesn't have a home directory defined, so I confused about upload directory. Prompt me the true linux way. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the point of the `go` tag on this question, it seem irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The true "Linux" way is to have a config file somewhere that defines that value and default to `/var/lib/app-name/`.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to store my applications in a separate partition where I will create a folder and give permissions for the daemon user.